# Automate parameters passing to super()

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance, parameter-passing, super

I have a parent class such as:

```js
class Animal {
  constructor({name, color}) {
    // Does something with name and color.
  }
}
```

Then I have many classes that extend Animal. For example:

```js
class Lion extends Animal {
  constructor({name, color, tailLength}) {
    super({name: name, color: color})
    // Does something with tailLength.
  }
}
```

My problem is that this code is not very DRY. For example, I may need to add a new parameter to Animal:

```js
class Animal {
  constructor({name, color, height}) {
    // Does something with name, color and height.
  }
}
```

Now I also need to change the interface of `Lion` and if I have 100 more classes who extend `Animal` I need to change those too.

Is there a way to rewrite this code so that all parameters of `Animal` are implicitly added to classes that extend it?

Comment: Is `super({...arguments[0]})` what you want?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mL3GAN) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  (Note that TypeScript's [structural typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) means that extra properties don't violate a type, so if you have some reason why you need to explicitly *block* extra properties, I hope you'll [edit] in an example that demonstrates that reason.)

Comment: @jcalz Yes, that's perfect actually. If you can write a stand-alone answer I'll mark it as correct. :)

Comment: "*I may need to add a new parameter to `Animal`, now if I have 100 more classes who extend `Animal` I need to change those too.*" - well that's not unreasonable. If you **are changing the interface** of a constructor, you must also change every location where it is called. This is normal, it's the same for functions, methods, class constructors. Your actual problem would be having 100 classes inheriting from `Animal`, that sounds like a code smell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use a single config-like object as any animal-related constructor's sole parameter, you should make use of the [*rest parameter syntax*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) in order to allow a generic and extensible approach.

```js
class Animal {
  constructor({ name, color /* and anything the OP might furtherly want */ }) {
    // does currently something with name and color.
  }
}
class Lion extends Animal {
  constructor({ tailLength, ...configRest }) {
    super(configRest)
    // does something with tailLength.
  }
}

// usage ase e.g.
const lion = new Lion({
  name: 'Simba', color: 'yellowish'/*, height*/, tailLength: 'long',
});
```